# How to get only one div to close when clicking close button on seperate divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to change in order to only get the separate preview window to close, not all that is opened at once. Have any tips?

```
function displayPreview(title, content) {
  const previewContainer = document.createElement('div');
  previewContainer.classList.add('preview-container');
  previewContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',
    `<div class="preview-modal">
            <div class="preview-content">
                <div class="preview-title">
                    <h3>${title}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="preview-text">
                    <p>${content}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="preview-close">
                    <button class="preview-close-button">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
  );
  document.body.appendChild(previewContainer);
  const previewCloseButton = document.querySelector('.preview-close-button');
  previewCloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    previewContainer.remove();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to confine the selector query for `previewCloseButton` to the appropriate scope rather than querying the entire document. This may work:

```
const previewCloseButton = previewContainer.querySelector('.preview-close-button');
```

Comment: That was a very simple fix! Thanks a lot. Im new to JS so not sure what i did exactly. But i guess i somehow only target a single div instead of all divs with that name?  Gon read up on it thx =)

Comment: Sure. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.